# how to add This plug in in Build.gradle (app)

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

***apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'***  <- where should i add this ?

so I recently installed a new version of android studio and there is a new format for the Gradel plugin so where can I put the apply plugin in the below code?

````
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
 }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.social.login2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the following lines

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
 }
```

to

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id ''com.google.gms.google-services' 
 }
```

instead of the apply plugin the way to use is now inside the plugins block give the id name and then the id within quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it at the end of your `build.gradle` file, as that's how it is recommended.

Or just as the last plugin in the `plugins` block up top